# Possible Error in Proving the One-Step Subgroup Test

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

The One-Step Subgroup Test is as follows:

"*Let $G$ be a group and $H⊆G$ be a subset of $G$. Then $H≤G$ if, and only if, $H$ is non-empty and $ab^{−1}∈H$ for all $a,b∈H$.*"

So I had asked a question before about this one, but this time, I'm now asking for some verification on proving the *converse* of the statement instead of proving the forward direction. In other words, showing that $H$ would be a subgroup as a result.

In one textbook I'm reading, the proof is as follows:

"*Since $H \neq \emptyset$, there exists an element $b \in H$ for which $bb^{-1} \in H$. But $bb^{-1} = 1_G \in H$, so therefore $1_G$ is the identity.*"

One of the main problems I see in this proof is that it doesn't show that $b^{-1}b = 1_G$ in $H$, and you can't automatically assume that it is since H is not necessarily commutative. So how would $1_G$ be the identity of $H$ then? Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A basic result in group theory:

> > If $ab=1$ then $ba=1$ (so $b=a^{-1}$).

Proof: $ba=ba(bb^{-1})=b(ab)b^{-1}=bb^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I think that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

$b^{-1}b=b^{-1}(b^{-1})^{-1}=(bb^{-1})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$, by the so-called "socks and shoes property".